# How to cross the Lake Constance from Constance to Meersburg by car

Tags: germany, europe, driving, lake-constance

I would like to visit Constance (Germany) with my van, and also see the other side of the lake. Is there a way to cross by ferry or would I need to drive along the lake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to cross by ferry as mentioned by [this website](https://www.meersburg.de/en/Tourism/Service-for-visitors/Navigation-Ferry):

> ## Ferry
>
> The car ferry Meersburg - Constance that can also be used by pedestrians or cyclists, makes trip planning even more flexible. There is another car ferry shuttle service between Friedrichshafen and Romanshorn.

Comment: [This website](https://www.stadtwerke-konstanz.de/schifffahrt/faehre-konstanz-meersburg/fahrplan/?no_cache=1) provides a timetable. Note that the given times constitute a minimal schedule. In times of heavy traffic the ferry runs more often.